# Get chooser activity name in android source

Tags: android

In my application, I'm checking the top activity name in background service and call a function if top activity is not Chooser activity in android by default. I found that activity name to be "**com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity**". So I'm hard-coding that and checking. Everything is working fine. But what happens when that activity name gets changed(Changed by google). So  my question is, Is there any way of getting the chooser activity in run-time?

Answer (score 0):

In your background service run a thread getting the top of the activity via ApplicationManager  then you can compare the top of the activity during runtime.

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);



 // get the info from the currently running task
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

 Log.d("topActivity", "CURRENT Activity ::"
         + taskInfo.get(0).topActivity.getClassName());

 ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
```

componentInfo.getPackageName();
You will need the following permission on your manifest:

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"

Comment: Thats what I'm doin now. I need a answer to how I get chooser activity name in runtime...